# how to take input from a file and store output to another file

Tags: linux, shell, pipe

i want input from a file for my user process and store the result in another file . i have done like:

```
$ ./a.out < inputFile.txt > outputFile.txt
```

this is working for me . but i m worried about redirection , for example what if inputFile.txt contents got redirected to outputFile.txt and then it is made availble to a.out.

i wanted to know is there any order for evaluation or atleast how the shell interprets the above lines.

Comment: `what if inputFile.txt contents got redirected to outputFile.txt and then it is made availble to a.out` Don't worry it won't happen. For more, read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122252/bash-expression-evaluation-order-on-command-line)

Comment: is this happen then i will not get output of the program stored in the file.(outputFile.txt).

Answer (score 0):

You can only redirect live entity to dead entity. You cannot redirect dead entity to live entity.

In your case file is dead entity. and ./a.out is live entity (which is a running process).

You can redirect ./a.out to file, but the reverse is not possible.

```
$ ./a.out > file  #should work

$ ./a.out < file  #will execute a.out and will not redirect file to ./a.out
```